# Counting the number of mobile phones in communication range with an Android phone

Tags: wi-fi

It is clearly possible to count how many WiFi devices are in the communication range using a computer with a wireless card. The idea apparently is [to sniff WiFi probe requests](https://github.com/schollz/howmanypeoplearearound) coming from the WiFi devices, including smartphones with WiFi enabled.

Here comes my question - is it possible to do the same using an Android smartphone instead of a PC? That is to say, can a phone WiFi be put in such a mode that it is able to count not only the access points in the range, but other devices as well?

Comment: Access to Wifi is more difficult the higher the Android version gets. And sniffing probe requests AFAIK requires raw access - which mean you need a rooted device. Additionally the used Wifi adapter has to support “Monitor mode” aka “Promiscuous mode”. A raw traffic capture app is e.g. this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.kismetwireless.android.pcapcapture Afterwards you would have to build a tool that processes the captured files and count what ever you need (e.g. MAC addresses).

Comment: @Robert thanks. why not add this an answer?

Comment: there was a sniffing app known as *"Reaver for Android"* but you need broadcom chipset and ancient android version. search for bcmon supported devices list